# Single SSD to Raid 1

Tags: windows, ssd, raid

Sorry ive never done this and want to make sure i dont lose my data, i have a 256GB SSD currently and i want to add a new 256GB SSD and run in raid 1, can i restore a windows image after i have setup my raid? i am also going to punt that i can not use my SSD cloner

I will be just be running the intel raid controller on windows.

I couldnt find anything definitive on google, some people said yes some people said no so im lost.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can restore Windows after you set up your RAID.  Intel RAID is hardware level RAID on the motherboard.  As far as the software restoring the image to your computer is concerned, it will only see one drive, the RAID1 mirrored volume.

On to the obligatory RAID is not a backup.  RAID saves you from drive failures, not from lost or corrupt data.  Always make backups of important data.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, a RAID 1 with the Intel® RAID Controller belongs to hardware RAID, doesn’t need to configure in Windows, doesn’t influence the content of disk, only create a mirror for your current disk.

After RAID 1 configured, you just see the same disk state as before, but both of your two SSDs have the same contents, which is used for the situation that one disk broken down.
How to Create a RAID Volume with the Onboard Intel® RAID Controller in UEFI Mode?
https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000030719/server-products/server-boards.html

One more thing, if you want a software RAID, Intel also has a product called Intel Rapid Storage Technology software, it helps user create RAID 1 in Windows
https://www.dell.com/support/kbdoc/en-sg/000149871/how-to-create-a-raid-1-volume-within-windows-using-the-intel-rapid-storage-technology-utility